# Cleaning xlsx files

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to wrangle messy large datasets from **xlsx** sheets. The table structures are such that the column headers are a combination of three rows.

I am using **RStudio** and trying to write a function that takes empty cells and fills them up with an attribute from previous filled cells, and finally concatenate all filled rows into one final column header with hyphens: e.g. *Employment*, *Number*, *Males* on three different rows should become `Employment_Number_Male`.

Any suggestions?

Please see the sample **xlsx** table I am working with.

[image: Sample xlsx table structure]

Answer (score 0):

Taking this data.frame:

```
    df <- data.frame(..1 = c("year", NA, NA),
             ..2 = c(NA, "males", "all"),
             ..3 = c(NA, NA, "half"),
             ..4 = c(NA, NA, "some"),
             ..5 = c(NA, "females", "all"),
             ..6 = c(NA, NA, "half"),
             ..7 = c(NA, NA, "some"))
```

Here is an attempt to convert empty cells to NA's..

```
    # convert empty cells to NA
    empty_as_na <- function(x){
    if("factor" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x) ## since ifelse wont work   with factors
    ifelse(as.character(x)!="", x, NA)}

   # transform all columns
   df %>% mutate_each(funs(empty_as_na)) 

    # apply function
    na.rows <- which( apply(df, 1, function(z) (all(is.na(z)) ) ) )
    df[na.rows , ] <- df[na.rows-1, ]
```

issue is filling it in with the value of the cell beside it..

[a reprex render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGXT1.png)

Comment: here's a synthetic data.frame to try on: